# How to use eval() with namespaced code?

Tags: php, namespaces, eval

I'm developing some kind of simple PHP shell witch I'll be using for quick debug (Like Yii framework's shell console command) I'm using readline lib and get code on line-by-line basics with history support.

Now when I enter `use Some\namespaced\code\class as alias;` in one line the second console command is not able to use `alias`.

Is it possible to pass `use` to main context, so subcommands can use aliases defined via `eval`?

Comment: Why dont you use PHPs built-in interactive console via `php -a`?

Comment: because i need the projects environment, config and etc. loaded, basically I want to be able to run code as I was inside a controller action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use :

http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php

But you can never 'unimport'.